# CSS - Hover on li a

Tags: html, css

I have HTML and CSS below.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="liHover">
        <a href="">Hover List</a>
        <div class="square1">
        Square 1
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="aHover">
        <a href="">Hover Link</a>
        <div class="square2">
        Square 2
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li {padding:20px; border: solid 1px;margin:5px;}

.square1, .square2 {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.liHover:hover .square1 {
  display: block;
}
.aHover a:hover .square2 {
  display: block;
}
```

Live sample is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uzyUr/38/)

If I have hover on `li`, it works, but if I move the hover to `li a:hover`, it doesn't work.

Below code is working.

```
.liHover:hover .square1 {
  display: block;
}
```

But this below code doesn't work.

```
.aHover a:hover .square2 {
      display: block;
    }
```

I wonder why? and how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because neither `.square1` or `.square2` is a child of any `a` tag.
Either add `.square1` or `.square2` class to the `a` tag, or make the `a` to parent over them.